# Fill Date Field using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

When I use iTextSharp to fill pdf, the date field looks like below, but other type fields looks good.
Does it mean that the format is not correct? Where/how can I got correct format? The date field filled manually is like `11 - Nov - 2019`.

[image]

Comment: No, the tag should indeed be iText, because "iTextSharp" is ye olde name of "iText for .NET". The API is, by design, exactly the same as "iText for Java". It doesn't matter in what language you use iText, the answer will most likely be the same. Also, here on Stack Overflow, `itextsharp` has been made an alias of `itext`. That makes it easier for people to find answers.

Comment: The format most likely is in javascript event listeners of the field.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thanks, I will remove the previous comment.

Comment: That's not necessary. It was a good question that would have benefited other readers.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, could you please send me more detail? Where can I get the javascript about this field? Thanks. I saw there are some screenshots showing the PDF's property's detail, but I'm not sure which tool can do that.

Comment: Can you share your PDF as an example of interest to you?

Comment: Sure, https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/form-listing/forms/1022.pdf, the date picker field is in the third page.